# embed offline shiny app in ioslides

Tags: r, shiny, knitr, r-markdown, ioslides

I'm making an ioslides presentation to demonstrate a shiny app that I developed earlier. The shiny app is embedded (inline) in a rmarkdown file. Since the conference room doesn't have internet connection, my thought is to run the app locally and render the html as an iframe in the ioslides, but it hangs every time I knitr the ioslides. I believe the issue is caused by the nested-rmd, since the shiny code-chunk can be loaded in the ioslides. Please let me know if you have some thoughts about it, thanks.

Comment: I had one question (will try finding the link) where my shiny-app wouldnt run in an .Rmd file. The solution was to remove the server- and ui-functions. By removing I mean that just remove the wrapper, leave all small input- and output-objects.  No idea why but it worked.